# common.js is not fount in Canvas lms production environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

When i am trying to run my canvas lms on localhost then this type of error occur "common.js not fount" but file is still there. I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your app/assets/application.js

```
= require 'common'
```

make sure common.js file is under app/assets/ or vendor/assets/